# Decrement value in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am creating a shopping application. Each user have wallet.
Structure is like :

```
{ 
    "userName" : "Gandalf the Grey",
    "wallet" : 100,
    "orderHistory" : []
}
```

Say this user buys something that costs 50 units. Is there a better way Instead of fetching its wallet value with findOne, then making substraction and updating new wallet value? Right now, I am making it with 2 different operations that looks like

```
dbo.collection('users').findOne({'userName': controller.userName})
.then(function(doc) { 
    updateWallet(doc); 
}
```

then

```
let newWalletBalance = doc.wallet - product.cost;
dbo.collection('users').updateOne(
    {'userName':controller.userName},
    { $set: {wallet: newWalletBalance } }
);
```

Is it possible to merge them into one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [**`$inc`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/) operator

```
db.collection('users').updateOne(
  { 'userName': controller.userName },
  { '$inc': { 'wallet': -product.cost } }
)
```

Comment: Why would you interpolate a numeric values as a string? In fact this would fail outside of mongoose ( which will cast the string as numeric by schema ) since your value to `$inc` is a string and not a number. Presuming `product.cost` is actually numeric ( and it should be if the code in the question actually works ) then it's just `-product.cost`

Comment: I have updated my answer. At first I thought it will throw error if I directly write `-product.cost` with minus sign. Thank you!!!